# Format of Draw.io XML file?

Tags: xml, mxgraph, draw.io

I created a shape in draw.io and exported it to get its XML file, which looks like this:

```
<mxlibrary>[{"xml":"vZTNcoIwEMefJnckXjxarF7aXvoEKawk05Blwirap+8SooLa0XbaZoaZ7H8/sssPImRW7VZe1foZC7BCPgqZeUTqd9UuA2tFmphCyIVI04QfkS6/8E6CN6mVB0f3JKR9wlbZDfRKLzS0t1EoPW5qIR88kiL1FuSE7ZgJnmA3Oj1H5yA/hB5bGHUVQmNLK8AKyO85pDUF6Rgxi2kaTKkPaTKKqonNHXNPQ/Imznl9Znkx8wsSNBeD89yugCKO22pD8FqrvPO2DIw1TRUfspjwttGqwPZgkMd3yNCiD6VkFhZ71sbagT4Lq9PR0UBfhsW6sqZ0rFlYU1eYzzeufArWYtpRgcZ8DKhUuB1YUJghsjGZJNS32M69x7aJyt2YhzjTn+H8DZrT21/wX4A8A9O9H5MrO48yYX0V1xjPObz/5rMfY7j59yXf58Xm6TYLvtFl9wk=","w":190,"h":130,"aspect":"fixed","title":"notes"}]</mxlibrary>
```

Is it possible to insert a new vertex using this data? I don't even know where to begin on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got this working. Check out the `mxCodec` example [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/io/mxCodec-js.html). So first, get the uncompressed xml for the node either as described by kjhughes or via the Extras -> Edit Diagram menu in Draw.io. Then you can add the node like so:

```
var xml = '<root><mxCell id="2" value="Hello," vertex="1"><mxGeometry x="20" y="20" width="80" height="30" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="3" value="World!" vertex="1"><mxGeometry x="200" y="150" width="80" height="30" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="4" value="" edge="1" source="2" target="3"><mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/></mxCell></root>';
var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
var elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
var cells = [];

while (elt != null)
{
  cells.push(codec.decode(elt));
  elt = elt.nextSibling;
}

graph.addCells(cells);
```

Replace `xml` with whatever the xml for your node is. Also, be sure not to include

```
<mxCell id="0"/>
<mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
```

as these are the default parents and their inclusion will break the graph by causing infinite recursion.

Answer (score 20):

You're looking at the XML compressed using the [Deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) compression algorithm.  Clearly you'll want to uncompress it prior to working with it.

[JGraph](https://github.com/jgraph), creators of the *excellent* [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) drawing/diagramming application, provide an [online decompression conversion tool](https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/convert.html).  Here's the `mxGraphModel` associated with your compressed data after uncompressing it with that tool:

```
<mxGraphModel>
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0"/>
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
    <mxCell id="2" value="" style="group;rotatable=0;" vertex="1" connectable="0" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry width="190" height="130" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="3" value="Notes" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;shadow=1;strokeColor=#CCCCCC;fillColor=#999999;fontColor=#FFFFFF;align=left;spacingLeft=4;resizable=0;movable=0;editable=0;connectable=0;allowArrows=0;rotatable=0;" vertex="1" parent="2">
      <mxGeometry width="190" height="30" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="4" value="" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;shadow=1;strokeColor=#CCCCCC;align=left;verticalAlign=top;spacingLeft=4;movable=0;resizable=0;connectable=0;allowArrows=0;rotatable=0;" vertex="1" parent="2">
      <mxGeometry y="30" width="190" height="100" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

See also [***Extracting the XML from mxfiles***](https://about.draw.io/extracting-the-xml-from-mxfiles/) on the [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) site.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not sure how to use this. The documentation is pretty sparse; are there any examples out there?

Comment: Just add a vertex manually in the program, save the XML, and compare the difference between the *before* and the *after* XML.  That will tell you exactly how the XML must be changed to add the vertex you want.  Then, write code to update the XML using your favorite programming language such as XSLT, JavaScript, Prolog, etc -- standard XML programming at that point.  Recompress as needed.

Comment: Alternatively, use their JS API.  A shape has an array of points into which you can add another:  [`mxShape.prototype.points`](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/shape/mxShape-js.html#mxShape.points)

Comment: Is there not an API that just allows me to add a shape based on the XML? I haven't been able to find one. I don't know what you mean by your first comment. You mean using graph.insertVertex? I'm sorry I'm new to mxgraph and having a hard time :/

Comment: You can either write generic XML processing code (using whatever language suits you) against the XML outside of their API, or you can use their JS API against their JS structures.

Answer (score 7):

I know the question has already been answered, but I'll pass the tip of what helped me.
In draw.io you go to the **File** menu and then to **Properties**, you have the option to **disable compression**. So when saving the xml it will be more readable and easier to edit.