# Merge changes on Draw.io (diagrams.net) files with Git

Tags: git, draw.io

**Context**: at my company, we document our architecture with multi-page Draw.io diagrams. These diagrams are included in a statically-generated documentation website. This works well, especially because we can link diagrams and website content.

**Problem**: now that the documentation has grown, we sometimes have several developer modifying the same Draw.io diagram in different Pull Requests. And Draw.io XML format is not very good at merging... so we had to resolve to "soft locking" the diagrams (with good old communication and .OWNERS files) to avoid 2 PR to modify the diagram at the same time.

I did not find any reference to a merging plugin. Latest versions of Draw.io desktop app and web editor allow collaborative editing, but I didn't find a way to start from that to write a merge tool. Any ideas how to proceed ? Do you have recommendations on the best way to handle that issue ?

Comment: Does draw.io provide some sort of mergetool/difftool?

Comment: You could make your own locking mechanism in order to prevent concurrent access.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Format of Draw.io XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416025/format-of-draw-io-xml-file), the `.drawio` filetype may contain either *raw XML* or *XML deflate-compressed* data.

This is also supported by the offical docs:

> The default format for saving diagrams was changed some time ago from raw XML to XML compressed using standard deflate. The main reason for this was that when Google’s server are struggling a compressed file has a much better chance of writing. That said, the raw XML may be useful to see how the diagram is constructed.
>
> https://drawio-app.com/extracting-the-xml-from-mxfiles/

You should be able to [disable XML compression](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/563) by setting `<mxfile compressed="false" ...>`.

So an approach could be:

- Work on uncompressed `.drawio` xml files only.
- Source control / diff / merge these files as human-readable text.
- Add an svn/png conversion process when building the static documentation site.

(I have only tested part of this, let me know if it works.)

Answer (score 1):

The following ( `drawio-difftool` ) is a custom bash script that I have written and use to perform visual diffs of drawio diagrams even when they are multi-tabbed. It does not solve the problem of merging, but gives you a  visual overview of the changes between versions, so that you can merge them manually.

It actually converts the two provided diagrams to images (the different tabs are presented one below the other on the same image) and opens them with an image-previewer (feh). Clicking on right/left arrows will switch between the two images. It also supports image-generation caching based on diagramname-hash combination.

It can easily be expanded to accept 2 to 3 diagrams instead of just 2 so that it can support 3-way-diff (case of mergetool).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# a difftool for drawio. It creates a composite image of all the pages of each of the diagrams and then opens the 2 images in feh.

# Usage with git: 
# simple: git difftool -x drawio-difftool path/to/diagram.drawio
# Or you map the tool to the .drawio extension via .gitattributes
# Can also be provided to git e.g. using --tool=  option (if it already registered as a difftool but the extension does not match)

USAGE="$0 drawio-file1 drawio-file2"

die() { echo $* 1>&2; exit 1; }

ostempdir=/tmp

infile1="$1"
infile2="$2"

[ $# -eq 2 ] || die "Usage: $USAGE"

test -f "$infile1" || die "cannot find file: $infile1"
test -f "$infile2" || die "cannot find file: $infile2"


if [ "$infile1" == "$infile2" ]; then
    echo "Warining: diffing the same file: $infile1"
fi

tempdir="$ostempdir/drawio-diff"
if [ ! -d "$tempdir" ]; then
    echo "Creating directory: $tempdir"
    mkdir -p "$tempdir" || die "cannor create temp dir $tempdir"
fi

# num of internal diagradms of each diagram
infile1pages=$(cat "$infile1" | grep -o "<diagram" | wc -l)
infile2pages=$(cat "$infile2" | grep -o "<diagram" | wc -l)

# note: number of pages may be the same but the diagram names may have changed. 
# Detecting tab name changes is not supported for now.
if [ $infile1pages -ne $infile2pages ]; then
    echo "WARNING: Differrent number of pages between documents: $infile1pages vs $infile2pages"
elif [ $infile1pages -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "WARNING: more than one pages found in documents: $infile1pages"
fi

infile1md5=$(md5sum $infile1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
infile2md5=$(md5sum $infile2 | awk '{ print $1 }')

outfile1noext="$tempdir/$(basename $infile1).$infile1md5"
outfile2noext="$tempdir/$(basename $infile2).$infile2md5"


for i in $(seq 0 $(($infile1pages-1))); do
    outfile="$outfile1noext.$i".png
    echo "generating image to : $outfile"
    if [ -f "$outfile" ]; then
        echo "Skipping $outfile generation because it exists. It seems the preview has already been generated in the past a file with the exact same name and md5"
    else
        drawio "$infile1" --export --page-index $i --output "$outfile"
    fi

done

for i in $(seq 0 $(($infile2pages-1))); do
    outfile="$outfile2noext.$i".png
    echo "generating image to : $outfile"
    if [ -f "$outfile" ]; then
        echo "Skipping "$outfile" generation because it exists. It seems the preview has already been generated in the past for a file with the exact same name and md5"
    else
        drawio "$infile2" --export --page-index $i --output "$outfile"
    fi

done




outfile1=$outfile1noext.png
outfile2=$outfile2noext.png


echo "merging the following image files to one image:" $outfile1noext.*.png
montage $outfile1noext.*.png -tile "1x$infile1pages" -geometry +0+0 "$outfile1"

echo "merging the following image files to one image:" $outfile2noext.*.png
montage $outfile2noext.*.png -tile "1x$infile2pages" -geometry +0+0 "$outfile2"

echo "previewing with feh"
feh --scale-down "$outfile1" "$outfile2"
```

Usage:

```bash
git difftool -x drawio-difftool path/to/diagram.drawio
```